# html/CSS Got issues with a wrapper not wrapping completely

Tags: html, css, wrapper

So as the title says I'm having issues with a wrapper not wrapping the content properly but leaving a small gap at the bottom.

[Image showing gap at bottom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fkOij.png)

html

```
<div id="newsContainer">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img class="newsImage"src="Bilder/exempel320x320.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img class="newsImage"src="Bilder/exempel320x320.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img class="newsImage"src="Bilder/exempel320x320.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img class="newsImage"src="Bilder/exempel320x320.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img class="newsImage"src="Bilder/exempel320x320.jpg">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper">
                <img class="newsImage"src="Bilder/exempel320x320.jpg">
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.newsImage {
    transition: all .2s ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
#newsContainer {
    position: relative;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 8%;
    margin-right: 8%;
    margin-top: 90px;
}
.newsImage:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
    border: 1px solid orange;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Have you used the developer's tools to see which element gives this space beneath it?

Answer (score 1):

Your images are rendered inline by default, thus treated as letters like "p", "q" and so on which require some space beneath the baseline. You can easily fix this by making your images block elements:

```
.newsImage {
  display: block;
  /* ... */
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your succinct and useful answer.  Here's a fiddle demonstrating your solution: https://jsfiddle.net/y411v9n1/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, this issue was definetly starting to give me a headache!